# Umbraco publish images issue

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, umbraco, umbraco7

Using Umbraco 7.1.4, Visual Studio 2012, C# .net 4.5, SQL server 2008.

I have recently set up my website on my Staging server.
I published the umbraco project as i normally do with other projects. Compressed the publish and ftp transferred it onto my staging server. Then I extract all files into a new folder version.

On the server I copy the last publish into a new version e.g 1.1. After which I copy all files **EXCEPT** the media folder.

Reason is, the first publish I did with the media folder screwed up, it couldn't locate the images as I suspect due to a ID issue.  So i had to delete all references and redo the images on staging.

So now ive been adding new functionality to the site and need to update my staging site to a new version.

However publishing the new version and using the previous version media does not work, references still dont work.

Is there another issue with Umbraco I need to factor in when publishing?  Is there something specific I need to do with the media folder?

Note that I also exclude files in the root such as the web.config etc, as I usually do on all my sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that You need to use the CMS admin section to publish all content pages and children.  I also noticed that You need to do this every time the version is upgraded regardless of previous version publish, therefore it appears you must do this process after you have increased the site version with you new publish.

Hope this helps anyone interested, or maybe someone can give a more in-depth reasoning behind this - what seems to be an intended- process